# Pex4Fun - Linking Phone and Website

Tags: pex

I have recently come across Pex4Fun, which happened to be by downloading the Windows Phone App. I have been using this for a little while and assumed that if I went to the Pex4Fun website, I would be using the same account as on my phone because I would be logging in with the same Windows ID as used on the phone.  This doesn't appear to have happened. Does anyone know if there is a way of linking the phone account and website account/windows ID so that I can switch between phone and website and have my points tracked?

Comment: Have you tried to logon using live id in browser?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov - Yes, I have logged in using my live ID in the browser.  That is what has surprised me - when I do I have 0 points and no nickname, there is no connection with the nickname and points that I see on the phone.